# Chart on MS Access 2003 ADP report

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

What's the best method of displaying report data in a chart format in an Access 2003 ADP project? I know this can be done in normal MDBs but this seems to use a Jet Crosstab query behind the scenes and this is not available in the ADP. I've experimented with the Office 11 Chart control but this seems a bit hit and miss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit a bit of a blank with this one but after some experimentation I've had some success with the Office 11 Chart. It's a bit inflexible programmatically but it's charting capabilities are very much like Excel's and it works quite well for static (non-parameterised) reports.

Comment: For parameterise data sources, you can bind the graph to a saved QueryDef and edit it before running the report. This is the way I've driven a report with a graph that shows Top N, where N is chosen by the user at runtime.